# AIMP 3 Repeats One Track In Playlist

Tags: media-player, playlists, aimp

When I'm trying to play a playlist, it plays the first track and then repeats it. How to make it play the next track instead?

Comment: Funny, Aimp 4.7 is doing the same thing to me.  Even though it's also set to Normal and not to repeat.

Answer (score 2):

When a single track keeps replaying, there are multiple options that can cause that.

1. Make sure the Track Repeat button isn't turned on.
2. In Options -> Automatic.  Playback Mode should be set to Normal.
3. In Options -> Automatic.  On End of Playlist should be set to Stand By.

In many cases, the third location is likely the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Open preferences and under player - automatic, select playback mode - Normal.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what skin you use, but look for the **Track Repeat** button (or context menu option) and disable it.

On the default skin for example the button seems to be the one with the two arrows located immediately on top of the **Play ►** button:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when the queue has a different order than the playlist.
The queue overrides the playlist order.
In this case, the repeating track might have been listed multiple times in the queue.

To fix that,  press CTRL + Q  to access the queue manager and clear that list.